# await Task не содержит определение Delay

Tags: c#, async-await

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private async Task PageLoad(int TimeOut)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> PageLoaded = null;
    PageLoaded = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    int TimeElapsed = 0;
    _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (_webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;
        if (PageLoaded.Task.IsCompleted) return; PageLoaded.SetResult(true);
    };

    while (PageLoaded.Task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        TimeElapsed++;
        if (TimeElapsed >= TimeOut * 100) PageLoaded.TrySetResult(true);
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

Почему VS пишет что `Task` не содержит определение для `Dеlay`? Вроде для ее работы нужна только `System.Threading.Tasks` или опять что-то поменялось?

Comment: проверь чем у тебя является _Task_. [Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) это статический метод класса _System.Threading.Tasks.Task_

Comment: кхм, а чем он может являться и как это проверить

Comment: private async Task PageLoad(int TimeOut)

Comment: что должна показывать эта строчка кода?

Comment: _а чем он может являться_ - например полем класса с таким именем, или параметром функции. Без [mcve] сложно сказать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) доступен с версии **.NET Framework 4.5**.

Есть аналог для **.NET Framework 4** в реализации [Microsoft Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

использовать так:

```
await TaskEx.Delay(1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот туда то я и не посмотрел. Вот что значит чужой код править. Да стоял .NET Framework 4

Comment: @blakcat, Пожалуйста, рад что помогло!